# How To play soud when AlertDialog is show

Tags: android, audio, dialog, alert, playback

when I play a sound file the sounds stops after a second. How can I make sure the sound keeps playing?

```
final Button BtPlaySound = (Button) resultdialog.findViewById(R.id.BtPlaySound);
BtPlaySound.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //play sound

    /*final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(ActivityMain.this, R.raw.r);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(100,100);
    player.start();
    */
    Context context = ActivityMain.this;

    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.r);
    try {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.r);
        } 
        mp.start();
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    //End Of PlaySoundFunction
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear can u explain little more please

Comment: Use start() and pause(), make sure you handle the errors, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: how i can to play sound when show alert dialog?